# different shortcut behavior during unattended installation

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I am trying to create a Start Menu shortcut. This is the code I'm using:

```
<Fragment>
    <SetProperty Id="MIFOLDER" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]\MI" Before="CostFinalize"></SetProperty>
    <!-- Start menu -->
    <Icon Id="iconCMD" SourceFile="$(var.SharedComponents.ProjectDir)Images\Icons\cmd.ico" />
    <DirectoryRef Id="STARTMENUFOLDER">
      <Component Id="cmp211060161C737F50377C120FF39D7623" Guid="{E7B9FB15-4A1D-4E3E-BCDE-EB2E5638C452}" Win64="yes">
        <Shortcut Id="shrtct211060161C737F50377C120FF39D7623" Name="Management Interface (MI)"
          Target="[System64Folder]\cmd.exe" Icon="iconCMD" Arguments='/k "title Managment Command Line Interface (MI)"' WorkingDirectory="MIFOLDER" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\$(var.Manufacturer)\VB\Installer\$(var.ProductName)\MI"
          Name="MI" Type="string" Value="$(var.VersionNumber)" KeyPath="yes" />
        <RemoveFolder Id="rem211060161C737F50377C120FF39D7623" On="uninstall"/>
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>
```

I want this shortcut to run Command Line Interface and start it in installation folder.

When running the setup normally, it indeed works fine and all well.

When I'm installing with /q (unattended), and after installation I click the shortcut, and it leads to Windows\system32 directory and not working directory. When I look at shortcut properties, I see that it set to start at \MI as SetProperty action doesn't take place.

Any help and ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**InstallUISequence** will be skipped in silent installation. Use `Sequence`attribute to run the SetProperty action as per your requirement(both or first).